# Merging to lists of different length to for list of dictionaries

Tags: python-2.7, list, dictionary, merge

Hi please help me develop a logic which does following.

```
list_1 = [1,2,3]
list_2 = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i]
```

Required output (List of dictionaries):

```
output = [{1:a,2:b,3:c}, {1:d,2:e,3:f}, {1:g,2:h,3:i}]
```

My script:

```
return_list = []
k = 0
temp_dict = {}

for i, value in enumerate(list_2):
    if k <= len(list_1)-1:
        temp_dict[list_1[k]] = value
        if k == len(list_1)-1:
            k = 0
            print temp_dict
            return_list.append(temp_dict)
            print return_list
            print '\n'
        else:
            k = k + 1
print return_list
```

My output:

```
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}
[{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}]


{1: 'd', 2: 'e', 3: 'f'}
[{1: 'd', 2: 'e', 3: 'f'}, {1: 'd', 2: 'e', 3: 'f'}]


{1: 'g', 2: 'h', 3: 'i'}
[{1: 'g', 2: 'h', 3: 'i'}, {1: 'g', 2: 'h', 3: 'i'}, {1: 'g', 2: 'h', 3: 'i'}]


[{1: 'g', 2: 'h', 3: 'i'}, {1: 'g', 2: 'h', 3: 'i'}, {1: 'g', 2: 'h', 3: 'i'}]
```

As you can see, temp_dict is getting printed correctly, but return_list is the last temp_dict 3 times.
please help to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you are not reseting `temp_dict` to a new object.
When you append it to the list, it still maintains the reference to the dict object, after you change it on the next loop, it changes the value on the array because it's the same reference.

If you reset the value it should work

```
list_1 = [1,2,3]
list_2 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']

return_list = []
k = 0
temp_dict = {}

for i, value in enumerate(list_2):
    if k <= len(list_1)-1:
        temp_dict[list_1[k]] = value
        if k == len(list_1)-1:
            k = 0
            print temp_dict
            return_list.append(temp_dict)
            temp_dict = {} # Here is the change
            print return_list
            print '\n'
        else:
            k = k + 1
print return_list
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
list_1 = [1,2,3]
list_2 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']

output = []

j = 0
for i in range(1, len(list_1) + 1):
    output.append(dict(zip(list_1, list_2[j:i * 3])))
    j = i * 3

print(output)
```

The assumption is that you second list is exactly 3 times larger than the first list.

Answer (score 0):

```
def merge_them(list1, list2):
    output = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(list_2):
        output.append(dict(zip(list_1, list_2[i: i + len(list1)])))
        i += len(list1)

    return output
```

and you can test it:

**test1:**

```
list_1 = [1,2,3]
list_2 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']
print merge_them(list_1, list_2)
```

you will get:

```
[{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}, {1: 'd', 2: 'e', 3: 'f'}, {1: 'g', 2: 'h', 3: 'i'}]
```

**test2:**

```
list_1 = [1,2,3,]
list_2 = ['a','b','c','d','e']
print merge_them(list_1, list_2)

you will get:

[{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}, {1: 'd', 2: 'e'}]
```

**test3:**

```
list_1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
list_2 = ['a','b','c','d','e']
print merge_them(list_1, list_2)

you will get:

[{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd', 5: 'e'}]
```